# Runtime disable the datagridviewcombobox

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I change the following things of a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` at runtime:

1. How do I set the first value of the combo box as default?
2. Disable combo box/make it read-only while showing the first value as default. Meaning to say, if I have 3 items in the combo-box it should show only the first item. (Either disable the combo box drop down, or change it to become a text box at runtime).

**Reason:**
The reason I do that is because for my `Enum` I have `Status{New=1,Stop=2,Temp=3}`. When i want to register a student, the status is always set to `New`. So when I save, it will auto save the `Status = 1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how to set the default value and disable the cell:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            Column1.DataSource = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            Column1.DataPropertyName = "Number";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = new[] 
            { 
                new { Number=1 },
                new { Number=2 },
                new { Number=3 },
                new { Number=1 }
            };
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == Column1.Index && e.RowIndex == (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

                cell.Value = 2;
                cell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
                cell.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Josh M.: There is no Enabled properties too ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dg.Columns["Status"]).En...

Comment: Are we not talking about the same control? This control has both properties I mentioned: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol.aspx

Comment: I've updated my answer with what should be a complete solution. You can use the CellFormatting event to override how the cell is displayed.

Comment: @Josh M.: Hi your solution works great. But one problem, the combobox is always readonly. I would like it to be Readonly when adding new user. When updating user it should be back to normal combobox populating those enum value. How do i put validation at the cellFormatting there? i also observe that it everytime also enter into this cellformatting event

Comment: This event is fired whenever a cell needs to be updated. I've updated my answer with code to only update the last (new) row. This is not the best solution probably but I'm not very familiar with this control.

Comment: @Josh M.: thanks your solution works if it do no enter into that event. Whenever i add new row which is the dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1, then it will auto change all the combobox above to be readonly. please hlep.

Comment: @Josh M.: could it something Cell.Row[lastRow].Readonly = true?

Comment: That's what this code is doing with the [e.RowIndex == (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)] portion of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

there is SelectedIndex for DataGridView combobox controls as per these articles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol(v=vs.80).aspx

[1]. This is how I do it:

```
private void dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Control is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl) {


    DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl control = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;


    BindingSource bs = control.DataSource as BindingSource;
    if (!IsNothing(bs)) {

        // set the filteredChildBS as the DataSource of the editing control
         ((ComboBox)e.Control).DataSource = filteredChildBS;

        //Set the dgv's combobox to the first item
         ((ComboBox)e.Control).SelectedIndex = 1

    }
}
```

}

The filtereredChildBS is a bindingsource, let me know if you need any clarification?

[2]. Disabling datagridview controls its a little trickier. I used this example to disable DataGridView checkboxes: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/988c7e3f-c172-467d-89b7-b80a60b7f24f/  but for comboboxes an easier way would be to disable columns bands:

```
foreach (DataGridViewBand band in dgvTransactions.Columns)  { if (i !=7) band.ReadOnly = (bool)i == 0;       i+= 1;  band.Frozen = false;  }
```

Let me know if you need further clarification?

Comment: thanks for the reply. But what is TryCast in c# ? i cannot find or write TryCast in visualstudio framekwork 3.5

Comment: sorry I ported from VB.Net using CodeChanger.com and it stuffed up the casting. Instead of TryCast use this syntax:((ComboBox)e.Control).SelectedIndex

Comment: what is filteredChildBS? should i load all the enum into this?

Comment: waht is i in if (i !=7) band.ReadOnly