# How to disable the DataGridViewComboBox in DataGridview?

Tags: datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

Hi Programmers!
                   I need to disable the DataGridViewComboBoxCell if the certain conditions get true. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you're working with windows form or wpf?

Comment: @Michele:Yes, you are right i'm working with windows form.

Comment: Have a look to [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373548/runtime-disable-the-datagridviewcombobox